# Cannot connect dockerized ASP.NET Core app to dockerized SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, docker, asp.net-core

I have just configured the project to connect to a dockerized SQL Server. `add-migration` and `update-database` commands via VS worked so I think the connection string is fine. I'm guessing it has something to do with the built app being in a container. I don't use `docker-compose`. I plan on running them separately.

The app successfully ran but it shows this error when performing actions with the database and shows this error:

> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
> while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
> found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
> and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
> (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to
> SQL Server)

The documentations couldn't help me out. Other questions similar to this but none of the solutions worked such as the `AllowRemoteConnections` set enabled (already enabled by default).

Comment: Are the Docker containers residing in the same Docker network so that they can communicate with one another? Is that Docker network the default `bridge` network? The default `bridge` network does not have DNS resolution for container names so they must address one another using their IP addresses, or you need to mess around with the legacy `--link` option. One of the benefits of docker-compose is that it creates a DNS-enabled network for the composition and deploys all of the containers into that - meaning containers can communicate with one another using names.

Comment: See also: [Differences between user-defined bridges and the default bridge](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge)

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Looks like docker-compose can make things simple.